# Can blood that has had an anticoagulant added to it be boiled without coagulating?

Tags: hematology

If I understood the information I've found elsewhere correctly, you can't boil untreated blood without it coagulating, right? But what if you added an anticoagulant to it? Would it be possible to boil that blood or would it coagulate in spite of it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Coagulation, or clotting, is a proteolytic cascade that generates an insoluble fibrin based protein net, or mesh.

Anticoagulants are things like EDTA (?) that chelate divalent cations required for the clotting cascade.

Boiling blood will denature most, if not all, of the soluble serum proteins, forming an insoluble precipitate.  This is structurally different from a blood clot.

Think about what happens to the white part of a chicken egg when you boil (or heat) it.  That is protein denaturation.